# How to get remaining stock from Product Advertising API (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm looking for [attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_response_elements.html) from AWS that show remaining stock. But no attribute found. So, Is it possible to get remaining stock or some thing that show me "In stock" or "Out of stock".

     
Actually, I found some solution "Web Scraping" but it's slowly and not work when web site doesn't show remaining stock.

Thank you
Mr. SaenD

Answer (score 0):

Amazon PAA don't offer stock details example how many items are on stock write now, only thing is offering is Availibility attribute

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AvailabilityValues.html

For this you have to use Offer response group